# Websdriver - sendKeys command is not typing on Password type field

Tags: selenium, webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to learn selenium webdriver automation but I am finding that the sendKeys command is not typing on Password type fields. I can see that some other people are also experiencing the same problem by googling it, but I haven't seen any correct answer yet. Could anyone please help me here.

Please find below sample code; I generated code from Selenium IDE and its working fine on IDE but not when I use webdriver.

```java
package com.example.tests;

public class Login {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.webs.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testLogin() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("FWloginUsername")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("FWloginUsername")).sendKeys("aug2qatestingqa@yahoo.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("FWloginPassword2")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("FWloginPassword2")).sendKeys("webs");
    driver.findElement(By.id("sign_in_leaf")).click();

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working"?  Does it throw an error, or simply not type it in?

Comment: Sorry, I should have more specific. It simply not type in it.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong.  Are you absolutely sure its not typing it in?  It may be running too fast that you cannot see it typing/logging in.  I would recommend debugging it and running it command by command.

Comment: Your id for the password field is FWloginPassword2 which makes me suspect that perhaps its not looking at the right element?  Is therea FWloginPassword element without the 2?

Comment: Yes there is FWloginPassword and FWloginPassword2 fields. If I use FWloginPassword2 and click on password field then it starts typing on it. So I think webdriver can't identifying the field.

Comment: @MrTi : org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 30.10 seconds

Comment: Ah, it found it, but it is not visible.  I believe that PocketDews is correct.  Try typing in FWloginPassword.  If that doesn't work, inspect the element (Chrome: Right-click->inspect element) and try to find a different element to select.

Comment: Found a solution but it actually weird. When I click FWloginPassword and then sendkeys command starts typing on FWloginPassword2 field. driver.findElement(By.id("FWloginPassword")).click(); driver.findElement(By.id("FWloginPassword2")).sendKeys("webs");  Thanks MrTi and @PocketDews

Comment: Hi Anoop Philip: glad to hear that you've found a solution. It's best if you post it as an answer, and then accept that answer; it helps everybody see the solution clearly, and marks the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two password fields and one is hidden. Solution is to click on first password [hidden] field to get second password field enabled.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("FWloginUsername")).sendKeys("aug2qatestingqa@yahoo.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("FWloginPassword")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("FWloginPassword2")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("FWloginPassword2")).sendKeys("webs");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had almost a similar situation for Password field. There were two elements for the same 'Password' field but with different IDs. The JavaScript was toggling "type = password"  on run time for a click, clear or any action to this field.

Solution in this case is to find the text with input `type = password`,

for example:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='password']")).SendKeys(IWebElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I used `ActionChains` which caused the later fields not being filled when using send_keys method.

The solution was to call `actions.reset_actions()`

e.g.

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_keys("a").perform()
actions.key_down(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_keys("c").perform()
actions.reset_actions()

# now send_keys() method works again
```

Answer (score -3):

```
cvvTxtBox().sendKeys("1234"); 
cvvTxtBox().sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Final Solution on this problem.
Else use Robot